# Iterating through two identical data sources

Tags: c#, linq

I have data with the same schema in a pipe delimited text file and in a database table, including the primary key column.

I have to check if each row in the file is present in the table, if not generate an INSERT statement for that row.

The table has 30 columns,  but here I've simplified for this example:

```
ID       Name    Address1    Address2    City    State    Zip
```

ID is the running identity column; so if a particular ID value from the file is found in the table, there should be no `insert` statement generated for that.

Here's my attempt, which doesn't feel correct:

```
 foreach (var item in RecipientsInFile)
        {
            if (!RecipientsInDB.Any(u => u.ID == item.ID ))
            {
               Console.WriteLine(GetInsertSql(item));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the asking the actual question; how to do this? 
Thank you very much for all the help.

EDIT: The table has a million plus rows, while the file has 50K rows. This a one time thing, not a permanent project.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @BalaR I meant to ask  how to do this. Sorry.

Comment: Feelings aside, what happened when you ran that code?

Comment: What specific section can't you do or are having problems with doing?

Comment: If you have an index on `RecipientsInDB` then this is O(N * log N), which is reasonable. Creating correlated queries would allow you to improve this to O(N), but at the cost of more complex code; don't optimize at the expense of complexity unless you have to.

Comment: `The member 'Recipient.ID' has no supported translation to SQL.` I get this at the `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways of accomplishing this. Yours is one way.

Another would be to always generate SQL, but generate it in the following manner:

```
if not exists (select 1 from Recipients where ID == 1234)
    insert Recipients (...) values (...)
if not exists (select 1 from Recipients where ID == 1235)
    insert Recipients (...) values (...)
```

Another would be to retrieve the entire contents of the database into memory beforehand, loading the database IDs into a `HashSet`, then only checking that `HashSet` to see if it exists - would take a little longer to get started, but would be faster for each record.

Any of these three techniques would work - it all depends on how big your database table is, and how big your file is. If they're both relatively small (maybe 10,000 records or so), then any of these should work fine.

**EDIT**

And there's always option D: Insert all records from the file into a temporary table (could be a real table or a SQL temp table, doesn't really matter) in the database, then use SQL to join the two tables together and retrieve the differences (using `not exists` or `in` or whatever technique you want), and insert the missing records that way.

Comment: The file has 50,000 rows, and the database table has 1 mill+ rows

Comment: In that case, it comes down to how many differences you're expecting. If a lot (or you don't know), I'd go with the `if not exists` method - even though you'd be generating a big SQL statement, it would all execute in one big swoop. If you're expecting a small number of differences, then I'd go with the `HashSet` - a million ints is still not terrible to store in memory and do a lookup on - here you'd have one big query plus a small number of little ones. I'd avoid doing a lookup for each record in this case - that would guarantee 50,000 individual queries, plus the inserts.

Comment: Or option D - see edit. And on my previous comment, I meant one big SQL script, not one big statement. It would be a lot of little statements.

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing the ID lists using `.Except()`

```
List<int> dbIDs = Recipients.Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();
List<int> fileIDs = RecipientsFile.Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();
List<int> toBeInserted = fileIDs.Except(dbIDs).ToList();

toBeInserted.ForEach(x=>GetInsertSqlStatementForID(x));
```

For the pedantic and trollish among us in the comments, please remember the above code (like any source code you find on the interwebs) shouldn't be copy/pasted into your production code. Try this refactoring:

```
foreach (var item in RecipientsFile.Select(x=>x.ID)
                                   .Except(DatabaseRecipients.Select(x=>x.ID)))
{
   GetInsertSqlStatementForID(item);
}
```

Comment: Consider this blog link when it comes to using `IEnumerable.ForEach()` instead of a plain `foreach`, other than that +1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @LukeHennerley That link seems to be broken

Comment: @FMFF not for me it isn't. Google `linq foreach vs foreach` and it should be the second link from `blogs.msdn` :)

Comment: @FMFF The site went down for a short while earlier, but it seems to be back up.

Comment: Also note that you really shouldn't have all of these `ToList` calls all over the place.  You're unnecessarily eagerly evaluating the entire queries when they can be streamed instead, allowing for a much smaller memory footprint.

Comment: @Servy This isn't production code. This is to illustrate. Please feel free to edit my answer to show a 2nd snippet on how it might be improved. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @p.campbell And what are the ToList calls illustrating?  How are they improving anything at all.  In this context it's like adding a bunch of `WasteSomeSystemResources` calls all over the place.  It adds nothing, hurts some things, and if the OP isn't smart enough to know that they need to be removed, those disadvantages will stick.  If he is smart enough to know that they need to be removed you're just wasting some of his time well he goes around removing them.  So why did you take the time to add those harmful method calls?  It can be fixed very simply, just remove every call to `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

I would add all the RecipientsInDB Ids in a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb301504.aspx) and then test if the set contains the item Id.

```
 var recipientsInDBIds = new Hashset(RecipientsInDB.Select(u => u.ID));
 foreach (var item in RecipientsInFile)
    {
        if (!recipientsInDBIds.Contains(item.ID ))
        {
           Console.WriteLine(GetInsertSql(item));
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```